# iPod Nano keeps going/staying in recovery mode

Tags: itunes, ipod

Configuration:
Windows XP Pro + SP3
iPod Nano 1st generation, firmware version 1.3.1
iTunes 10.4.1.10

---

When I connect the iPod to the PC iTunes says

> iTunes has detected an iPod in recovery mode. You must restore
>   this iPod before it can be used with iTunes

OK, that's what I do. I get a message that

> Your iPod has been restored to factory setting, and is
>   restarting. Please leave your iPod connected. It will
>   appear in the iTunes window after it restarts.

Then on the iPod the Apple logo appears for a few minutes, which then switches to a "Do not disconnect" message. Again after some time the recovery mode reappears in iTunes. I've cycled through this a few times, even on a different USB port, but no avail. If I disconnect the iPod I can walk through the menus, and reset it. The music of course has gone.

Is there a way to get the iPod out of recovery mode, other than with the iTunes function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a drive letter conflict in Windows. Go ahead and try the steps listed here: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1493#changedrive

Comment: That's exactly it. I found it out myself as well, but this is the right answer, so you get the votes

Answer (score 0):

I looked a bit further in it and I found the solution [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1493#changedrive). It appears the drive letter assigned to the iPod conflicted with another drive. Assigning a free drive letter as on the Apple support page solved the problem.